# Unit testing method that returns bool

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Let's consider a method `bool Validate(Request req)`. The specific implementation doesn't matter.

But the thing we know is that this method always return `true` or `false`. And now I see problem with unit testing method like this below.

We can test whether it returns `false` when validation fails for many cases, e.g. user is not adult, has not enough role to access some resource etc.

But we can't determine where the `false` is returned. So unit test can be successful but due to different reason than expected.

Currently, to check whether `false` is returned where I want to return it (and this is specified by concrete test method where it should be returned) I set breakpoint on this `return` statement and run concrete unit test method. If test stops on this breakpoint I'm sure unit test is not lying.

But this approach seems primitive to me. How shall I write unit tests for methods that returns `bool`?

Comment: Option 1. You code your test such that it passes all the other checks, but fails the one you are after.

Comment: Option 2. You alter your `Validate` method to provide more information such as why it failed validation, and check that as well (also good as it allows users to know why the data is failing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But we can't determine where the false is returned

Do you actually care? The main point is that correct contract/requirement is respected, i.e. if you set up a `Request` with only one "wrong" property - you get the expected result - `false`. So you need to write the corresponding amount of tests which perform the needed set up and cover corresponding contracts/cases.

Note that quite often the reason why validation has failed is required by business or at least for logging purposes, so you might want to consider returning not a simple `bool` but some kind of `ValidationResult` which will contain the `bool` and failure reason(s).

P.S.

Consider using [`FluentValidation`](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation) which can save you some time making your own implementation.

Comment: I second the recommended lib. We use it and it has the advantage that it comes with test helpers to test the validators.

Answer (score 0):

> I set breakpoint on this return statement and run concrete unit test method. If test stops on this breakpoint I'm sure unit test is not lying.

I'd recommend TDD, gut the whole Validate method out and start with an exception being thrown. Then, introduce use cases one by one. You write the test so it fails because the code has not been implemented. Double check there is a failure then write the code so it passes the test. The point of this exercise is so you don't "lie" like you said in the test. It's part of the TDD red/green/refactor dev flow.